# Where is the root list of CRDs that `operator-courier verify` wants me to update?

Tags: kubernetes, sdk, kubernetes-custom-resources

When running `operator-courier verify` against my Operator Bundle built using the Operator Framework's operator-sdk, I'm getting the following error.

```
ERROR: custom resource definition REDACTED referenced in csv not defined in root list of crds.
```

I have it in spec.customresourcedefinitionns.owned which is why I assume it knows about it at all.

Where is the "root list" of crds I need to add this to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. The reason for this issue was the incompatible CRD names in the custom resource definition YAML and the CSV file.

The `metadata.name` of the CRD YAML and the `spec.customresourcedefinitions.owned.name` of the CSV file should be the same.

If you need to know more information about how this validation works in `operator-courier`, please refer to [this python implementation](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-courier/blob/e8e35729ab759b765319b9d8ea56a6794471c2f7/operatorcourier/validate.py#L197).